# Promise in event publish ionic 2

Tags: angular, events, promise, ionic2

I am trying to learn about event publish and subscribe in ionic 2.
Is it possible to add a promise as a parameter in an event.

```
events.publish('done',promise);
```

When i subscribe to it, its giving promise.then is not a function.

```
events.subscribe('done',(promise)=>{
  promise.then(()=>{
   console.log('Fulfilled');
  }
```

But instead of using the promise in the event publish,if i directly use it as

```
promise.then(()=>{
 console.log('Fulfilled');
}
```

Its working.

Comment: `When i subscribe to it, its giving promise.then is not a function` what is `typeof promise`?

Comment: typeof promise is giving me an object.

Comment: I meant in the subscribe code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, When you publish something inside a publish functions, its an Object not a function.

Just check ***typeof Promise*** in subscribe code is an Object not a function.

So you can't do that.